# how to return true in bash if all conditions success ?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

is there any specific way to check if the condition true on for loop and return true.
ex -

`

```
 check_all_1_to_8_eq()
{
 for i in {1..8}; do 
      if [ a == $i ];then
          return 0
      else
          return 1
      fi
done
}`
```

i want to check if all 1 to 8 are return true then end of the function return true , if on of the if condition return false , then function return false. Please let me know how to solve these type of script.

Comment: Also note that `for i in {1..8}` case `[ a == $i ]` will always be false. But I presume `a` is a placeholder and It will be replaced by something like `$a`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continue looping if the condition succeeds, and `return` outside the loop. If the condition fails, `return` at that point:

```
check_all_1_to_8_eq () {
    for i in {1..8}; do 
        if [ ! a == "$i" ]; then
            return 1
        fi
    done
    return 0
}
```

`[ ! a == "$i" ]` checks if value of variable `i` (`$i`) is *not* equal to `a`.

---

You can leverage short circuit evaluation, `||` (runs the command following it only if the preceding command fails) too, here we will do the equity check `[ a == "$i" ]`:

```
check_all_1_to_8_eq () {
    for i in {1..8}; do 
        [ a == "$i" ] || return 1
    done
    return 0
}
```